# Group python pandas dataframe per weeks (starting on Monday)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with values per day (see df below).
I want to group the "Forecast" field per week but with Monday as the first day of the week.

Currently I can do it via pd.TimeGrouper('W') (see df_final below) but it groups the week starting on Sundays (see df_final below)

```
import pandas as pd
data = [("W1","G1",1234,pd.to_datetime("2015-07-1"),8),
        ("W1","G1",1234,pd.to_datetime("2015-07-30"),2),
        ("W1","G1",1234,pd.to_datetime("2015-07-15"),2),
        ("W1","G1",1234,pd.to_datetime("2015-07-2"),4),
        ("W1","G2",2345,pd.to_datetime("2015-07-5"),5),
        ("W1","G2",2345,pd.to_datetime("2015-07-7"),1),
        ("W1","G2",2345,pd.to_datetime("2015-07-9"),1),
        ("W1","G2",2345,pd.to_datetime("2015-07-11"),3)]

labels = ["Site","Type","Product","Date","Forecast"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=labels).set_index(["Site","Type","Product","Date"])
df


                              Forecast
Site Type Product Date                
W1   G1   1234    2015-07-01         8
                  2015-07-30         2
                  2015-07-15         2
                  2015-07-02         4
     G2   2345    2015-07-05         5
                  2015-07-07         1
                  2015-07-09         1
                  2015-07-11         3



df_final = (df
     .reset_index()
     .set_index("Date")
     .groupby(["Site","Product",pd.TimeGrouper('W')])["Forecast"].sum()
     .astype(int)
     .reset_index())
df_final["DayOfWeek"] = df_final["Date"].dt.dayofweek
df_final

  Site  Product       Date  Forecast  DayOfWeek
0   W1     1234 2015-07-05        12          6
1   W1     1234 2015-07-19         2          6
2   W1     1234 2015-08-02         2          6
3   W1     2345 2015-07-05         5          6
4   W1     2345 2015-07-12         5          6
```

Comment: I think `W-MON` instead `W` should help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have three solutions to this problem as described below. First, I should state that the ex-accepted answer is incorrect. Here is why:

```py
# let's create an example df of length 9, 2020-03-08 is a Sunday
s = pd.DataFrame({'dt':pd.date_range('2020-03-08', periods=9, freq='D'),
                  'counts':0})
> s
```

|  | dt | counts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-03-08 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 1 | 2020-03-09 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 2 | 2020-03-10 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 3 | 2020-03-11 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 4 | 2020-03-12 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 5 | 2020-03-13 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 6 | 2020-03-14 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 7 | 2020-03-15 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 8 | 2020-03-16 00:00:00 | 0 |

These nine days span three Monday-to-Sunday weeks. The weeks of March 2nd, 9th, and 16th. Let's try the accepted answer:

```py
# the accepted answer
> s.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='dt',freq='W-Mon')).count()
```

| dt | counts |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-03-09 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 2020-03-16 00:00:00 | 7 |

This is wrong because the OP wants to have "Monday as the first day of the week" (not as the last day of the week) in the resulting dataframe. Let's see what we get when we try with `freq='W'`

```py
> s.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='dt', freq='W')).count()
```

| dt | counts |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-03-08 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 2020-03-15 00:00:00 | 7 |
| 2020-03-22 00:00:00 | 1 |

This grouper actually grouped as we wanted (Monday to Sunday) but labeled the 'dt' with the END of the week, rather than the start. So, to get what we want, we can move the index by 6 days like:

```py
w = s.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='dt', freq='W')).count()
w.index -= pd.Timedelta(days=6)
```

or alternatively we can do:

```py
s.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='dt',freq='W-Mon',label='left',closed='left')).count()
```

a third solution, arguably the most readable one, is converting `dt` to period first, then grouping, and finally (if needed) converting back to timestamp:

```py
s.groupby(s.dt.dt.to_period('W'))['counts'].count().to_timestamp()
# a variant of this solution is: s.set_index('dt').to_period('W').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W')).count().to_timestamp()
```

all of these solutions return what the OP asked for:

| dt | counts |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-03-02 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 2020-03-09 00:00:00 | 7 |
| 2020-03-16 00:00:00 | 1 |

Explanation: when `freq` is provided to `pd.Grouper`, both `closed` and `label` kwargs default to `right`. Setting `freq` to `W` (short for `W-Sun`) works because we want our week to end on Sunday (Sunday included, and `g.closed == 'right'` handles this). Unfortunately, the `pd.Grouper` docstring does not show the default values but you can see them like this:

```
g = pd.Grouper(key='dt', freq='W')
print(g.closed, g.label)
> right right
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `W-MON` instead `W`, check [anchored offsets](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets):

```
df_final = (df
     .reset_index()
     .set_index("Date")
     .groupby(["Site","Product",pd.Grouper(freq='W-MON')])["Forecast"].sum()
     .astype(int)
     .reset_index())

df_final["DayOfWeek"] = df_final["Date"].dt.dayofweek
print (df_final)
  Site  Product       Date  Forecast  DayOfWeek
0   W1     1234 2015-07-06        12          0
1   W1     1234 2015-07-20         2          0
2   W1     1234 2015-08-03         2          0
3   W1     2345 2015-07-06         5          0
4   W1     2345 2015-07-13         5          0
```

Comment: `TimeGrouper` is [now deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0210-deprecations)